# Was Shiva really cursed and did his phallus really fall to the ground as claimed in this image?

Tags: shiva, translation-request, shiva-purana, curse, devi-bhagavata-purana

[This](https://www.instagram.com/p/CG42dyBluff) Instagram handle posted the following image claiming Shiva's phallus fell to the ground after he was cursed by a rishi. Is this story really present in the said scripture?

> [image]

[image: the slokas as given. may be translation be wrong]

May be the translation is wrong. Can someone tell right translation? Can anyone translate sloka number 36-37?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123081/discussion-on-question-by-pasham-vishnu-vardhan-goud-was-shiva-really-cursed-and).

Comment: These are interpolated Puranic stories and were invented for ignorant masses of Kaliyuga. Shiva linga is a symbolical combination of Purush-Prakriti and can be seen practically within any being's eyes where eye is a metaphor for yoni(body or Prakriti) and pupil of linga(mark of Purusha/Atma) i.e. pair of Kshetragya(seer)-Kshetra(seen) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kshetrajna)

Answer (score 5):

It is not Shiva's own penis but the the penis of a hideous form which Shiva took **to test his own devotees.** Full story is in the Shiva Purana, Koṭirudra-Saṃhitā, Chapter 12 - The reason for Śiva’s assuming the phallic form (liṅga):

> Śiva himself assuming a very hideous form came there in order to test their devotion. He was very brilliant but stark naked. He had smeared ashes all over his body as the sole ornament. Standing there and **holding his penis he began to show all sorts of vicious tricks.**

> The wives of the sages were extremely frightened at this sight.

> **The sages, deluded by Śiva’s Māyā and plunged in grief, began to say—“Who is this? Who is this?”** When the naked sage did not reply, the great sages told that terrible Puruṣa - “You are acting pervertedly. **This violates the Vedic path. Hence let your penis fall on the ground.”** When they said thus, the penis of that Avadhūta, who was Śiva of wonderful form, fell down instantly. That penis burnt everything in front; wherever it went it began to burn everything there. It went to Pātāla; it went to heaven; it went all over the earth; it never remained steady anywhere.

> Brahma said:- "O brahmins, you though wise do such despicable things. Then why complain against the ignorant who act likewise? Who can wish for happiness after offending and antagonising Śiva thus? ...... **As long as the penis does not become stationary there cannot be anything good in the three worlds**...... Let the gods propitiate goddess Pārvatī and pray. **If she can assume the form of the vaginal passage that penis will become steady.** "

> Lord Śiva said:— If my penis is supported in a vaginal passage there will be happiness. Except Pārvatī, **no other woman can hold my penis. Held by her my penis will immediately become quiet.**

> After propitiating Pārvatī and the bull-bannered lord and performing the rites mentioned before, **the excellent penis became static.**

> That phallus was held by her in that form then. **When the phallus was stabilised, there was welfare throughout the worlds. O brahmins, that phallus became famous in the three worlds.**

So it is the penis of a hideous form Shiva took in the ancient past.

Answer (score 1):

We all are aware of the fact that how Puranas are corrupted. We can only know the corrupted portion when:

1. We see contradictions
2. Something dont make any sense.

While, second point can be due to lack of spiritual maturity also. But when majority find 2 one true, than there is really problem with verse only.

It is clear that it is interpolation.

Because, in one case, Lord Shiva burns Kama dev to ashes and in another he is described being caught in lust.

It proves both point.

Comment: this looks like personal opinion. Add references.

Comment: Sir, indeed it is personal opinion. But with some logic also.