# Is panchayatan puja mentioned in bhagavatam?

Tags: advaita, bhagavata-purana, adi-shankaracharya

Do bhagavatam mention punchayatan puja. And do bhagavatam says all five Gods(devatās) are equal?

Comment: Its mentioned in Mahabharata - the Fifth Veda

Comment: I went form bhagavatam

Comment: Bhagavata is a Vaishnava Purana. You can get Vishnu=Shiva=Brahma but not Panchayatna. No Purana will because they are either vaishnava/shaiva/shakta

Comment: But padma Purana tells about panchayatna , linga Purana tells , Devi bhagavatam tells

Comment: And I have other question I thick you can answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45852/19353