# What is the explanation for Devi bhagavatam 4:20:36?

Tags: shiva-lingam, devi-bhagavata-purana, commentary

What is the explanation and commentary (if any) that Sri Nilakantha Dikshita has provided for Devi Bhagavatam 4:20:36-37? Is the translation for the same available?

> [[Devi bhagavatam 4:20:36-37]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57184.html) : O King! When Mahādeva, being infatuated with Kāma, went into the forest of Bhṛgu and becoming naked, began to copulate, the ascetic Bhṛgu, seeing him in that state, exclaimed “O You are very shameless” and cursed Him thus :-- Let your penis drop off just now. Mahādeva, then to satisfy his thirst for passion, began to drink the water of the lake Amrita Vapī, dug by the Dānavas.

Comment: "What Nilakanth explain to Devi bhagavatam 4:20:36-37 and translation that commentary:" --- I didn't understand this portion so didn't edit it.

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45852/647 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Nilakanth tells in Devi bhagavatam 4:20:36-37?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/what-nilakanth-tells-in-devi-bhagavatam-42036-37)

Comment: Plz any one tell

Comment: But who was he was having relations with ? It wasn’t Parvati, right ? I’ve been wondering